# How to split by a group with constraints

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem.

for example, we have 10 groups of people:

Group 1: 20

Group 2: 5

Group 3: 15

Group 4: 10

Group 5: 12

Group 6: 26

Group 7: 41

Group 8: 15

Group 9: 69

Group 10: 9

we are trying to load those groups of people into a number of buses, BUT can't break the group.  Each bus can only carry 80 people.  Any suggestions on r code/function to get me the minimum amount of buses needed.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a "partitioning" problem. Do some searches in SO and the web for solutions with the keyword "partition". There are several question that I suspect are duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bin-packing problem for which you can find plenty of approaches online.

Anyways, here's a solution with greedy algorithm. This doesn't guarantee optimal solution but should be decent enough -

```
grp <- c(20, 5, 15, 10, 12, 26, 41, 15, 69, 9)
cap <- 80

sorted_grp <- sort(grp, decreasing = T)

buses <- list("bus_1" = NULL)
for(g in seq_along(sorted_grp)) {
  balance_cap <- cap - sapply(buses, function(x) sum(x))
  if(any(balance_cap >= sorted_grp[g])) {
    feasible_bus <- which(balance_cap >= sorted_grp[g])[1]
    buses[[paste0("bus_", feasible_bus)]] <- c(buses[[paste0("bus_", feasible_bus)]], sorted_grp[g])
  } else {
    buses[[paste0("bus_", length(buses) + 1)]] <- sorted_grp[g]
  }
}

# > paste0("Number of buses: ", length(buses))
# [1] "Number of buses: 3"
# > buses
# $`bus_1`
# [1] 69 10
# 
# $bus_2
# [1] 41 26 12
# 
# $bus_3
# [1] 20 15 15  9  5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response, Shree!  It works great!  +1.  Unfortunately my vote is only recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score because my reputation is less than 15.  Your solution is succinct and elegant!  Also thank you for pointing me to further reference (bin-packing problem).

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed number of containers this can be formulated as an integer linear programming problem.  If `g` is a vector of the 10 group numbers and `cap` is the capacity, i.e. 80, then there must be at least `k=ceiling(sum(g) / cap)` containers and no more than `k=length(g)` .  Thus we successively fit from the minimum to the maximum number of  containers stopping as soon as we get a fit.  In the case of the data shown in the problem (see Note at end) only one iteration is needed.

In the `lp` problem there are k by n binary variables and if we arrange them in a k by n matrix then the i,j-th is 1 if the ith container contains element j and 0 otherwise.

The lp problem has k+n constraints.  The first k constraints constrain the sum of each of the k containers to `cap` and the remaining `n` constraints ensure that each element can only occur in one container.

```
library(lpSolve)
stopifnot(all(g <= cap))

n <- length(g)
kmin <- ceiling(sum(g) / cap)
for(k in seq(kmin, n)) {
  objective.in <- rep(1, k * n)
  const.mat <- rbind(diag(k) %x% t(g), t(rep(1, k)) %x% diag(n))
  const.dir <- c(rep("<=", k), rep("==", n))
  const.rhs <- c(rep(cap, k), rep(1, n))
  res <- lp("min", objective.in, const.mat, const.dir, const.rhs, all.bin = TRUE)
  if (res$status == 0) break
}

# iterations
k - kmin + 1
## [1] 1

# solution - each col is an element, each row is a container 
matrix(res$solution, k, byrow = TRUE)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    0     0
## [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     1
## [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
```

### Note

The input used was this:

```
Lines <- "Group 1: 20
Group 2: 5
Group 3: 15
Group 4: 10
Group 5: 12
Group 6: 26
Group 7: 41
Group 8: 15
Group 9: 69
Group 10: 9"
g <- read.table(text = Lines)$V3

cap <- 80
```

Comment: Thank you, G. Grothendieck!  It works great!  I actually will be using linear programming for another project.  This is perfect!